# I want to set collectionview height with maxY of last collectionviewcell! But why SE simulator doesn't work?

Tags: collectionview

I want to set collectionview height with last item's maxY (not scrollable collectionview /  grid collectionview / fixed width&height).

I get last index of item and get last item's layout using `collectionView.layoutAttributesForItem(at: lastIndex)`
and get maxY of the item and set collectionviewHeight to maxY.

But only SE simluator can't find correct maxY of last item?!

I don't know why SE simluator can't find correct maxY of last collectionview cell...

Here is my code (full code at [github](https://github.com/eunjin3786/BibleCheckList)):

```
class CheckListTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    var book = Book()

    @IBOutlet weak var bookNameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionViewHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!

    var estimateWidth = 30.0
    var cellMarginSize = 3.0

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        setCollectionView()
    }


    func setCollectionView(){
        collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "PageCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "PageCollectionViewCell")
        self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        if let flow = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout{
            flow.minimumInteritemSpacing = CGFloat(self.cellMarginSize)
            flow.minimumLineSpacing = CGFloat(self.cellMarginSize)
        }

    }

    class func instanceFromNib( _ book:Book)->CheckListTableViewCell{

        let cell = UINib(nibName: "CheckListTableViewCell", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil)[0] as! CheckListTableViewCell
        cell.book = book
        cell.bookNameLabel.text = book.title
        cell.collectionView.reloadData()
        cell.setCollectionViewHeight()
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCell.SelectionStyle.none
        return cell
    }
}


extension CheckListTableViewCell:UICollectionViewDataSource{

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return book.pageList.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "PageCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as? PageCollectionViewCell else{
            return UICollectionViewCell()
        }

        let page = book.pageList[indexPath.row]
        cell.pageNumberLabel.text = page.pageNumber
        return cell
    }

}

extension CheckListTableViewCell:UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout{

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let width = self.calculateWith()
        return CGSize(width: width, height: width)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let page = book.pageList[indexPath.row]
        RealmManager.shared.changeIsReadOfPage(title: book.title, pageNumber: page.pageNumber, isRead: !page.isRead)

        if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? PageCollectionViewCell{
            cell.toggle(isRead:!page.isRead)
        }

    }


}


extension CheckListTableViewCell{

    func calculateWith() -> CGFloat {
        let estimatedWidth = CGFloat(estimateWidth)
        let cellCount = floor(CGFloat(collectionView.frame.size.width / estimatedWidth))

        let margin = CGFloat(cellMarginSize * 2)
        let width = (collectionView.frame.size.width - CGFloat(cellMarginSize) * (cellCount - 1) - margin) / cellCount

        return width
    }


    // it is very clean & simple to set collectionview height with maxY of last collectionview cell
    // But only SE Simulator maxY is not correct why????!

    func setCollectionViewHeight(){

        let lastIndex = IndexPath(item: book.pageList.count-1, section: 0)

        if let att = collectionView.layoutAttributesForItem(at: lastIndex){
            collectionViewHeight.constant = att.frame.maxY
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: But I recommend that you go in and improve the formatting of your code. Empty lines should be used intentionally to **group** things that belong together. Random empty lines just make it harder to read your code!